NETMIKO use Microsoft 2FA code for SSH to Cisco device
Which parameter I should use to input the authenticator code what I saw at my mobile?
import netmiko
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

ip = '192.168.100.100'
equip = {
 'device_type' : 'cisco_ios',
 'ip' : ip,
 'username' : 'my_username',
 'password' : 'my_password',
}
connect  = ConnectHandler(**equip)
print('Successfully connected to', ip)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 1137, in establish_connection
    self.remote_conn_pre.connect(**ssh_connect_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 485, in connect
    self._auth(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 818, in _auth
    raise saved_exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 805, in _auth
    self._transport.auth_password(username, password)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1603, in auth_password
    return self.auth_handler.wait_for_response(my_event)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/paramiko/auth_handler.py", line 263, in wait_for_response
    raise e
paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bobby/Python3/Netmiko/Test/netmiko_testname.py", line 32, in <module>
    connect  = ConnectHandler(**equip)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/netmiko/ssh_dispatcher.py", line 399, in ConnectHandler
    return ConnectionClass(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 488, in __init__
    self._open()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 493, in _open
    self.establish_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 1174, in establish_connection
    raise NetmikoAuthenticationException(msg)
netmiko.exceptions.NetmikoAuthenticationException: Authentication to device failed.

Common causes of this problem are:
1. Invalid username and password
2. Incorrect SSH-key file
3. Connecting to the wrong device

Device settings: cisco_ios 192.168.100.100:22

Authentication failed.

Use SSH to input authenticator code manually is working as below.
root@ubuntu01:~/Python3$ ssh -l username@xxxx.com 192.168.100.100

 YOU HAVE ACCESSED A PRIVATE FACILITY. IF YOU ARE NOT AUTHORIZED
 TO USE THIS FACILITY OR YOU HAVE BEEN INADVERTENTLY CONNECTED,
 PLEASE DISCONNECT NOW. INTENTIONAL AND UNAUTHORIZED ACCESS TO
 THIS NETWORK AND THE DATA HEREIN IS PROHIBITED AND WILL BE
 SUBJECT TO PROSECUTION.
(username@xxxx.com@192.168.100.100) AD Password: 'my_password'
(username@xxxx.com@192.168.100.100) Enter Your Microsoft verification code

Successfully to login after input the MS authenticator code that I saw at mobile.
I tried to add more parameter at Netmiko but it is not working.
